# Compare elements of an object resides in two list - one on one using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to find out is there any better way other than `Enumerable.Range` in WHERE clause to compare object's elements one on one.

It could be a parallel since We're comparing one on one here.

For example: `House.Windows[0].color != House1.Windows[0].color` and then movenext to
 `House.Windows[1].color != House1.Windows[1].color` and so on...

Type will be same in both list.

```
    public class House
{
    string HouseNmbr;
    List<Window> windows;

}

public class Window
{
    string WSize;
    string WColor;
    bool IsEnergyEff;
}

public static class MyMain
{
    void Main()
    {
        House h1 = new House
        {
            HouseNmbr = "1",
            windows = new List<Window> { 
                new Window {Wsize="1", WColor = "blue",IsEnergyEff = true},
                new Window {Wsize="1", WColor = "black"},
                new Window {Wsize="1", WColor = "red"}
            }
        };

        House h2 = new House
        {
            HouseNmbr = "1",
            windows = new List<Window> { 
                new Window {Wsize="2", WColor = "blue",IsEnergyEff = false},
                new Window {Wsize="2", WColor = "black"}
            }
        };

        //Find the diffs...
        IEnumerable<House> updatesFromHouses = from id in h2 //Since h2 will have updates
                                             join pd in h1
                                             on id.HouseNmbr equals pd.HouseNmbr
                                               select new House
                                             {
                                                 windows = pd.windows.Where(
                                                    wn => Enumerable.Range(0, wn.windows.Count).All(ctr => wn.IsEnergyEff != id.windows[ctr].IsEnergyEff)
                                                 ).ToList()
                                             };            

    }
}
```

Comment: Paste some code, what type of output do you need?

Comment: I don;t understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Apologize for not pasting code for clear understanding.

Comment: @JackSmotheir and where is your Enumerable.Range? Is position in list matters here? E.g. what if second house will have black window first?

Comment: What exactly is your desired result?

Comment: Enumerable.Range is in where clause which will run a loop against h2.windows list. And I believe position does matter in windows list as one should match exact object to start finding diff.

Comment: @JackSmotheir OK if you have house1 with windows white and black, and house2 with window black and green, what windows you want in output? Also does size matter?

Comment: I guess It is about finding diff. in these elements if any then add the entire object to resulting list. Just updated code for more understanding. I know I've pasted only some code which is causing confusing for all of you.

Comment: @JackSmotheir can you please answer what is expected output for my example above, and does window size matter?

Comment: Window size does not matter - it is just a data field. Expected output will be a house object with 2 window objects inside windows list property since these 2 window objects have diff. when compared.                                                                           House h3
        {
            HouseNmbr = "1",
            windows =  { 
                Window {Wsize="2", WColor = "blue",IsEnergyEff = false},
                Window {Wsize="2", WColor = "black"}
            }
        }

Comment: @JackSmotheir Your query will not compile - h2 and h1 are not enumerable. What is house h3? What are expected results (see my questions above and please answer them)? Why in your last answer black window in results?? it has not changed.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Enumerable.Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) if you are comparing one by one:

```
House.Windows.Zip(House1.Windows, (w, w1) => w.color != w1.color);
```

This returns collection of boolean values for one by one comparison of colors. You can use `Any(b => !b)` to check if there is any non equal color.

Keep in mind, that both windows lists should have same length (only corresponding elements will produce result). So, you can start from checking length of lists before doing zip. If items count is different, then lists are not same.

---

In order to compare windows you should override Equals and GetHashCode methods:

```
public class Window
{
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnergySaving { get; set; }

    public Window() { }

    public Window(string size, string color, bool isEnergySaving)
    {
        Size = size;
        Color = color;
        IsEnergySaving = isEnergySaving;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Window other = obj as Window;
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return Color == other.Color &&
               IsEnergySaving == other.IsEnergySaving;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 19;            
        hash = hash * 23 + Color.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + IsEnergySaving.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Here is house class slightly improved:

```
public class House
{
    public House(string number)
    {
        Number = number;
        Windows = new List<Window>();
    }

    public string Number { get; private set; }
    public List<Window> Windows { get; private set; }

    public House WithWindow(string size, string color, bool energySaving = false)
    {
        Windows.Add(new Window(size, color, energySaving));
        return this;
    }
}
```

With this fluent API you can create houses like this:

```
House h1 = new House("1")
                .WithWindow("1", "blue", true)
                .WithWindow("1", "black")
                .WithWindow("1", "red");

House h2 = new House("1")
                .WithWindow("2", "blue")
                .WithWindow("2", "black");
```

And finding changed and new windows will look like:

```
var changedAndNewWindows = h2.Windows.Except(h1.Windows);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parallel.For in this context since you are comparing two lists element by element and without editing (if you need to edit you have to use lock):

```
var count = Math.Min(h1.Windows.Count, h2.Windows.Count);
Parallel.For(0, count, (index)=>{
//Do your operations here
if(h1.Windows[index].Color == h2.Windows[index].Color)
{
}
});
```